# Move cursor among lines inside the same paragraph?

Tags: cursor-movement

Inside a "logical" line (I mean a vim "paragraph" = chars sequence terminated by a LF/CR), I would like to move cursor from the phisical line where the cursor is positionated to near lines, (e.g. **one line UP or one line DOWN the current cursor position**).

By example, in the parapraph here below, I would like to move the cursor from the bottom line to one line up to sub-word "*rniamo*" and again one line up word "*atmosfera*".

[image]

There is a way to do it, just with a UP/DOWN cursor movement ?

Of course the workaround is to jump directly to the word (eg with `/atmosfera`), but that's time consuming.

Last but not least, I would prefere a way to do that in "insert" mode, if possible (or in normal mode).

Any idea ? Suggestions ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override your up and down movements to recognize wrapped text by remapping them to add the `g` key

```
nnoremap j gj
nnoremap k gk
```

Comment: For insert mode I use `inoremap <C-k> <C-o>gk` and `inoremap <C-j> <C-o>gj` btw.

Comment: thanks jecxjo and carpetsmoker, I do not remeber the meaning of command "g", but It work!

Comment: `g` is a prefix to _a lot_ of default mappings.  In this case, `gj` and `gk` move up and down one _visual_ line, not an actual line.  For more on all mappings beginning with `g`, see `:help g`.